# React-html-parser crushing the deployment

Tags: reactjs, next.js, html-parsing, html-parser

I am trying to deploy my next app on vercel and the react-html-parser is throwing error
I thought about downloading an older version of react but there are other dependencies that required newest version
Is there a solution for this case?

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-html-parser@2.0.2
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.9.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     @emotion/react@"^11.9.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.9.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!       @emotion/styled@"^11.9.3" from the root project
npm ERR!       4 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, @mui/x-date-pickers)
npm ERR!     4 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, @mui/x-date-pickers)
npm ERR!   24 more (@emotion/styled, @mui/base, @mui/icons-material, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-0" from react-html-parser@2.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-html-parser
npm ERR!   react-html-parser@"^2.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-0" from react-html-parser@2.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-html-parser
npm ERR!     react-html-parser@"^2.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /vercel/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **html-react-parser** instead of `React-html-parser`, the last release for `react-html-parser` in 2017

It's work for me, usage is same.

```js
import HtmlParser from "html-react-parser";
//...

{ HtmlParser("<h2>Hello World!</h2>")}

//...
```